# Under what circumstances can I use rundll32 to invoke a function in a DLL?

Tags: windows, rundll32.exe

I'd like to invoke the functionality found in various Windows DLLs from the command line. It looks like the `rundll32` utility will do what I need - it takes a DLL name and a function name, and runs that function with parameters.

I certainly hope there won't be any problems with that. What functions can I use `rundll32` on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are almost certainly going to be problems.

#### What functions can I use `rundll32` on?

Well, optimally, you wouldn't use it at all—it's [deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643):

> Rundll32 is a leftover from Windows 95, and it has been deprecated since at least Windows Vista because it violates a lot of modern engineering guidelines. If you run something via Rundll32, then you lose the ability to tailor the execution environment to the thing you’re running.

`rundll32` is only designed to call a very specific type of function, specifically, functions that create a window and process window messages. [This Microsoft document on the `rundll32` interface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787) explains that the function you're calling *must* take an `HWND`, a `HINSTANCE`, a `LPSTR`, and an `int` (in that order), and must use the `_stdcall`/`CALLBACK` calling convention.

Consult the MSDN documentation on the function you want to call to see whether it has that signature. For example, [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't fit. In fact, I can't find a single function with that signature that's documented.

If you're not sure what all of that means, you can skip the next section and go on to the final one.

#### What can go wrong if I use it on other functions?

Remember that whole function signature thing? **`rundll32` assumes the function you're trying to call has the right signature**, no matter whether that's actually the case. When its assumption is wrong, seriously bizarre stack-related stuff can go on. (The stack is a memory location that stores parameters passed between functions.)

Mismatched function signatures will result in the data provided by `rundll32` being interpreted as something different because of where the function expects its parameters to be on the stack. The first datum `rundll32` supplies is a window handle, which are assigned in a nondeterministic fashion. Therefore, if you misuse `rundll32`, **you're effectively passing random data as the first parameter**. Further reading: [What can go wrong when you mismatch the calling convention?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043)

The rest of the parameters don't work out any better. Even if you supply a command line to the function via `rundll32`, it's not going to get parsed into the data types appropriate for the function. Instead, `rundll32` just takes the entire "extra" text, jams it into a string variable, and passes a pointer to that data to the function as a later parameter. It's up to the function to parse the text. Therefore, there's no hope of ever invoking arbitrary functions with user-supplied arguments with `rundll32`.

It's not a complete disaster if the target function expects no parameters, but you're still messing up the stack. [There is code in `rundll32` to deal with that](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110909-00/?p=9683), but that doesn't give you an excuse to keep abusing it.

If you're using `rundll32` to invoke a compatible function in a third-party DLL that's designed to be used this way, you could still have problems. `rundll32` always opts in to all new Windows features (e.g. [Data Execution Prevention](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/875352)), which can introduce changes that the third-party code wasn't designed for; that's why the behavior is opt-in.

Fortunately, there's a better way to do what you want.

#### What can I do instead?

Trying to lock the workstation (`user32.dll,LockWorkStation`)? Just run `tsdiscon`.

Trying to shut down the system (`user32.dll,ExitWindowsEx`)? Use the `shutdown` utility with the appropriate flags—see `shutdown /?` for help.

Are you an application developer, and trying to invoke a DLL function of yours without writing a new EXE? Write that EXE, probably in C++.

Trying to run something else? My open-source utility [SprintDLL](https://github.com/Fleex255/SprintDLL) supports user-specified parameter lists, several calling conventions, and scripting to work with multiple functions and their outputs. If you prefer to only use Windows-included tools, you can do [P/Invoke with PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/).

---

> This question and answer were written as a reference usable for correcting materials that suggest using `rundll32` in a dubious fashion. If you see people abusing `rundll32`, give them a link to this page!

Comment: Thanks for the `ExitWindowsEx` function (or method even), I didn't know about that. To add, `tsdiscon` is for [tag:RDP] and there's `stop-computer` [tag:cmdlet] for shutting down.