# How to replace the Desktop background image with a solid color, using PowerShell and registry?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-registry, desktop, windows-insider

I would like to replace the default Desktop background image with a darker solid color, on an **unregistered** Windows 10 Pro (*Insider Preview*) edition. I am testing various terminal coloring schemes, and the default image is annoyingly too bright and not solid. I have tried all sorts of registry settings and also renaming and replacing the image, but it's always the same.

A few things I tried:

```
# Take (user) owbership of file:
takeown /F C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg
# C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg

$key = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Colors'         # 
$key = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'        # 
$key = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors' # 

# Doesn't seem to effect the Desktop...only console
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name 'Window' -Value '1 36 86'
# reset to default
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name 'Window' -Value '255 255 255'
```

**How can I use PowerShell to set the correct registry item(s) to remove the background image and get a solid color?**

Comment: `$key = "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop";Set-ItemProperty -Name WallPaper -Path $key -Value ''`

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ I must have found the solution while you were typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed I found two methods. One using `CMD-R` to run some windows magic, and another by setting the PATH value to null with (`''`).

However, [apparently](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-current-wallpaper-file-path-windows-10/) there is another registry item containing the path in hex encoded form, in `HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\TranscodedImageCache`, that you can see by the rudimentary hex conversion.

```
# Set the wallpaper PATH to ''
$key = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name 'WallPaper' -Value ''

# Re-start windows Explorer:
Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer

# Using `CMD+R` and run : 
shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper

# Getting the "Transcoded" PATH:
$TIC=(Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' TranscodedImageCache -ErrorAction Stop).TranscodedImageCache
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($TIC) -replace '(.+)([A-Z]:[0-9a-zA-Z\\])+','$2'

#C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\_img0.jpg
```

Also related to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/966650/path-to-current-desktop-backgrounds-in-windows-10).

- You need to restart windows `explorer.exe` (use *Sysinternal's Process Explorer* or PS with: `Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer`) in order for registry changes to take effect.

---

**UPDATE: 2020-01-09**

- You don't need to re-start explorer, nor compile anything via PoweShell, ... almost. From [THIS](https://fleexlab.blogspot.com/2017/06/changing-desktop-background-color-with.html) blog and [this](https://superuser.com/a/1215141/116221) SESU answer, I found a fantastic one-liner:

```
add-type -typedefinition "using System;`n using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`n public class PInvoke { [DllImport(`"user32.dll`")] public static extern bool SetSysColors(int cElements, int[] lpaElements, int[] lpaRgbValues); }"

# Now to get your desktop to instantly turn purple, run it with:
[PInvoke]::SetSysColors(1, @(1), @(0xAA40C0))
# Or tack it on the end of above for a true one-line experience.
```

Notes from author: *"This doesn't affect the Registry, so if you want the change to stick, you need to also write the new data to Registry yourself."*

Comment: Good point! In this case, you needn’t to restart `explorer.exe`. Right-click the desktop + _Refresh_ should suffice

Comment: Cool! Is there a powershell command to *refresh* desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I finalized the `not2qubit` solution by calling C#.
I cleared the current wallpaper and saved the new color value to the registry

Variable `$color` store new color to set.

Variable `$CSharpScript` store C# script to call.

Base code for C# get from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309943/c-set-desktop-wallpaper-to-a-solid-color

With `[SolidWallpaper]::SetWallpaper($color)` we could call created C# function, where `SolidWallpaper` is created class and `SetWallpaper` is created function

```
$color = 0xf0f0f0

$CSharpScript = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public class SolidWallpaper
{
  public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
  public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
  public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fWinIni);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern bool SetSysColors(int cElements, int[] lpaElements, uint[] lpaRgbValues);

  public static void SetWallpaper(uint color) {
    // clear current wallpaper and update ini
    SystemParametersInfo(SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, "", UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange);

    // set solid color
    int[] lpaElements = { 1 };
    uint[] lpaRgbValues = { color };
    SetSysColors(1, lpaElements, lpaRgbValues);

    // save to registry
    int rgb = (int)color;
    RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Colors", true);
    key.SetValue(@"Background", string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", (rgb >> 16) & 0xff, (rgb >> 8) & 0xff, (rgb >> 0) & 0xff));
  }
}
"@

add-type -typedefinition $CSharpScript
[SolidWallpaper]::SetWallpaper($color)
```